# t-sql: academic, looking for more efficient/better way to query

Tags: sql, group-by, union

This code works, but its very "old-schoolish" looking. Does anyone have a better way to select and group this in a single query? Basically, this is just a generic setup with a single header table, a subheader table for pickups, a subheader table for drop-offs and detail tables for each.

```
 select h.id
  ,h.col1 as Customer
  ,h.col2 as Req
  ,d.subid as DropId
  ,d.col1 as DropCity
  ,d.col2 as DropLoc
  ,dd.detid as DropDetailId
  ,dd.col1 as DropSpot
  ,dd.col2 as DropAWBorPackage
  ,NULL as PickupId
  ,NULL as PickUpCity
  ,NULL as PickUpLoc
  ,NULL as PickupDetailId
  ,NULL as PickupLoc
  ,NULL as PickupAWBorPackage
 from [scratch].GenericHeader h
   inner join [scratch].GenericSubHeader d on d.id = h.id
   inner join [scratch].GenericDetail dd on dd.id = h.id
     and dd.id = d.id
     and dd.subid = d.subid
 UNION ALL   
  select h.id
   ,h.col1 as Customer
   ,h.col2 as Req
   ,NULL as DropId
   ,NULL as DropCity
   ,NULL as DropLoc
   ,NULL as DropDetailId
   ,NULL as DropSpot
   ,NULL as AWBorPackage
   ,p.sub2id as PickupId
   ,p.col1 as PickUpCity
   ,p.col2 as PickUpLoc
   ,pp.det2id as PickupDetailId
   ,pp.col1 as PickupLoc
   ,pp.col2 as PickupAWBorPackage
  from  [scratch].GenericHeader h
    inner join [scratch].GenericSubHeader2 p on p.id = h.id
    inner join [scratch].GenericDetail2 pp on pp.id = h.id
      and pp.id = p.id
      and pp.sub2id = p.sub2id
  order by Req,DropId,DropDetailId,PickupId,PickupDetailId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get the same data in one SQL statement.  You might want to make two SQL queries, one for the drop-off data and a second for the pickup data.

Comment: thanks--I thought so, but I just wanted to be sure it wasn't just a "force of habit" thing! :)